# Does UIScrollView take more memory on zoom?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have an `UIScrollView`. My most of the operations are on the zoom level of `UIScrollView`. I test using `instruments`, at normal zoom level (i.e 1) its taking less memory but when I zoom its taking too much memory and crashing also.

Detailed scenario:

1. I took `UIView` as `subview` of `UIScrollView`. I am drawing some shapes on it.
2. I have to show information in these shapes when the `UIScrollView` zoomed. So I am adding information view on `UIScrollView` when zoomed and remove it when zoomed out.

I need to know, whether `UIScrollView` takes more memory on zoom or my approach is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIScrollView itself does not define drawRect: so it takes only small amount memory for storing its properties.

When zooming UIScrollView applies scale transform to the contents view returned from `viewForZoomingInScrollView:`. This does not change amount of memory consumed by the contents view, just changes its visible rectangle. So if your app crashes when zooming look at the code you execute when/after zooming.